# Project specific theme in sublimetext2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Am I missing something or does SublimeText2 lacks this feature/package?

What I want to achieve is when I have 2-3 project open at the same time have the windows visually distinct one from another, now, when I change the color scheme in one of the windows, it changes in other open SublimeText2 windows too. Pretty hard to work, when you have to look in the sidebar/titlebar to see the project name. It gets pretty annoying, when you have to copy-paste dozens of lines from one project to another or something similar.

Any package/configuration that will help me with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit the project settings, do something like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Amy.tmTheme"
  }
}
```

Use Preferences->Browse Packages to find the color scheme directories/file names.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to make it visibly distinct in any other way? In example - change only the color of the tabs?

Comment: You could install a new theme and specify a different theme.  Tab color is controlled by theme settings.

Comment: So no way to directly set any of the color scheme settings?

Comment: If it still doesn't work, try to remove `color_sceme` parameter from user settings (`Preferences -> Settings - User`)